# How to deploy an app using Kubernetes Azure and AWS SDK for java

Tags: java, azure, kubernetes, azure-sdk

```
public void runKubernetes() {
    KubernetesCluster k8sCluster = this.getKubernetesCluster("xyz-aks");
    System.out.println("___________________________________________");
    System.out.println("Kubernetes Cluster String: " + k8sCluster.name());

    DefaultKubernetesClient kubeclient = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
    System.out.println("Kube client Master URL :"+kubeclient.getMasterUrl());

    NodeList kubenodes = kubeclient.nodes().list();
    for (Node node : kubenodes.getItems()) {
        System.out.println( node.getKind() + " => " + node.getMetadata().getName() +": " + node.getMetadata().getClusterName());
    }
}
```

I get Client and nodes. Now, I have yaml file and I want to deploy that yaml (create service, deployment and pods) programatically.

I can do following

```
kubectl create -f pod-sample.yaml
```

but I want to do same thing using JAVA SDK.

I am using following java libraries for kubernetes:

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can parse the YAML or JSON of the deployment definition. For example, for YAML you can use any of the Java libraries [here](http://yaml.org/)

- [JvYaml](https://jvyaml.dev.java.net/)             # Java port of RbYaml
- [SnakeYAML](http://www.snakeyaml.org/)          # Java 5 / YAML 1.1
- [YamlBeans](http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/)          # To/from JavaBeans
- [JYaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/)              # Original Java Implementation
- [Camel](https://www.github.com/decorators-squad/camel)              # YAML 1.2 for Java. A user-friendly OOP library.

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) seems to be the more popular for JSON which also supports a YAML extension.

Then once you parse say the name, for example to create a service:

```
Service myservice = client.services().inNamespace(parsedNamespaceStr).createNew()
                     .withNewMetadata()
                       .withName(parsedServiceName)
                       .addToLabels(parsedLabel1, parseLabel2)
                     .endMetadata()
                     .done();
```

Comment: Hi Rico, This service creation works perfectly. But when I try to create deployment before service, it creates programatically, but I do not see in kubectl get deployments. Do you know if it is getting successfully created or not? How should I debug that?

Comment: the code I am using :
`Deployment createdDeployment = builderDeployment 
     .withKind("Deployment")
     .withNewMetadata().withName("server-proxy").endMetadata()
     .withNewSpec()
      .withNewTemplate()
       .withNewSpec()
       .addNewContainer().withImage(<public docker repo:image>)
        .addNewPort().withContainerPort(5000).endPort()
       .endContainer()
       .endSpec()
      .endTemplate()
     .endSpec()
     .build();
   System.out.println("Deployment: " + createdDeployment.toString());`

Comment: It might be getting created on a different `namespace`.  Can you check `kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces`?

Comment: I checked, I dont see any deployment with name `server-proxy`

Comment: I don't see how your call would have succeeded then.  Do you have any client logs? network traces?  Can you look at the `kube-apiserver` logs on your cluster?

Comment: How to associate DeploymentBuilder with kubernetesClient? Is this a valid question?